# Django include templates in markdown

Tags: python, django

I have Django templates written in Markdown. I'd like to implement template tag to include rendered markdown.

```
{% include_md 'mytemplate.md' }
```

I wrote template tag to render my template:

```
import markdown
from django.template import Library, loader, Context

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def include_md(context, template_name):
     t = loader.get_template(template_name)
     return t.render(Context({
         #...
     }))
```

but I need to put somewhere in the middle of my function something like:

```
markdown.markdown(template_content)
```

Unfortunately, template loader doesn't return content of template. So what is a best way to achieve rendering? I woudln't like to implement my own opening template methods with open().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django provides a convenience method **[`render_to_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string)** for situations like this:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def include_md(context, template_name):
     template = render_to_string(template_name, context)
     return markdown.markdown(template)
```